# CBLAS: Issue with *gbmv

Tags: c, blas

I am trying to use the BLAS function **dgbmv** to multiply a vector by a band matrix. My code is in C and I use cblas to call the function.

Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /*Band representation of A = {1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0 
                                2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0 
                                3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0 
                                4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0 
                                0.0  5.0  5.0  5.0 }*/

  double A[24]={0.,0.,1.,2.,
                0.,1.,2.,3.,
                1.,2.,3.,4.,
                2.,3.,4.,5.,
                3.,4.,5.,0.,
                4.,5.,0.,0. };

  /* Vectors x and y */
  double X[4]={1,2,3,4};
  double Y[10]={1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0};

  double  alpha=2.;
  double  beta=10.;

  /* Use BLAS to compute y=beta*y+alpha*A*x */
  cblas_dgbmv(CblasRowMajor,CblasNoTrans,5,4,3,2,alpha,A,6,X,1,beta,Y,2);
}
```

This code gives y={20.,0.,80.,0.,106.,0.,114.,0.,58.,0.} which is wrong.

However, if I use the transpose of A and change the first parameter of cblas_dgbmv to "CblasColMajor" I get the correct result:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      ....
      .... 
       double B[24];


       /* Set B=transpose(A) */
       int l,m;
       for (l=0;l<6;l++)
       {
           for(m=0;m<4;m++)
           {
             B[6*m+l]=A[l*4+m];
           }
       }
       ...
       ...
       cblas_dgbmv(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,5,4,3,2,alpha,B,6,X,1,beta,Y,2);
}
```

This code gives y={22.,0,60.,0.,90.,0.,120.,0.,140.,0.}, which is correct.

I think that both codes should produce the same result, since changing the matrix storage format from row-major to column-major and transposing the matrix should lead to no net effect.

I need to handle large matrices and I can not afford to transpose all of them. Moreover I would like to understand why the two examples give different results.

Comment: Values of A in code and comments differ. Explain.

Comment: As it says in the comment, the array A is the band matrix representation of the matrix A.
See http://goo.gl/1eAGFV for details.